# Change the Default page with MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to change the Default page `mydomain.com/Views/Home/Index.chtml` of an MVC application to point to another Default page in the application root `mydomain.com/Default.aspx`.

This is the default configuration of the MVC Default MapRoute. How can I change the configuration to point to `mydomain.com/Default.aspx`? I'm new to MVC and I'm trying to understand how the RegisterRoutes function works.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: MVC does not navigate to files - it navigates to action methods in controllers. What is the controller and method that returns that view.

Comment: Is Default.aspx a WebForms page?

Comment: Yes Default.aspx is a WebForm page.

Comment: Why you just convert your webforms page to a regular .cshtml page in mvc. After you can use the route mechanism by specifying the new Action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [URL Rooting in ASP.NET (Web Forms) - chsakell's Blog](https://chsakell.com/2013/12/15/url-rooting-in-asp-net-web-forms/), add this before the default MVC route:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("default", "", "~/Default.aspx");
```

You could also probably accomplish this using a filter, but it might be easiest just to do a redirect in the `Index` action of the `HomeController`.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
    }   
}
```

Comment: I've already used the redirect in the Index page but I thought that there was a "cleaner" way to do it.

Comment: Part of the problem is that the default ASP.NET MVC templates assume, by convention, that a request for the root URL is intended for the HomeController and it's Index action. Defaulting to a WebForms page is not exactly "normal" in a mixed project (in my admittedly limited experience, anyway). The PageRoute is probably the simplest alternative to a redirect. @StephenMuecke may have a better suggestion.

Comment: I've tried the return Redirect in the HomeController and it works well so far.... I'll try the other options described in here.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think more cleaner and correct way to do is to migrate your aspx page to a cshtml view and add this as a default route to your route.config

Otherwise a workaround is to redirect from the default route to aspx page.

Have a look at Scott's blog [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx)

Comment: I can't change any names or extensions because the website is an established one. Thus, I want to use what I have and try to solve it the best possible way.

Comment: I believe redirecting to default.aspx as the best way possible in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set route config  .

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        ).DataTokens.Add("area", "AdminMaster");
```

Here AdminMaster is Area , Conttroller Name is Admin and Action Name is Index .
If your default page in another Area , then you have to specify Area also .

Thanks .